# Conveying 'jump on the bandwagon'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Je me suis demandé comment on pourrait exprimer en français l'expression anglaise "jump on the bandwagon", qui signifie généralement rejoindre une tendance ou adopter une activité populaire qui gagne du terrain. (Voir, par ex., https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jump_on_the_bandwagon, https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump-on-the-bandwagon)

J'ai vu les traductions "sauter dans le train en marche" (qui me semble calque de l'anglais) et "suivre le mouvement" mais je me demande s'il existe d'autres façons idiomatiques de rendre cette idée.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[On a](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_le_train_en_marche#French) « prendre le train en marche » mais avec un sens d'opportunisme et tardivement semble-t-il ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_le_train_en_marche)). [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/bandwagon/564433) parle aussi de « suivre le mouvement » (péjoratif). Termium semble donner « [se mettre sur le rail](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=bandwagon&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) » ou simplement « appuyer/donner son appui/se joindre » mais ça semble avoir dans certains cas une connotation politique, comme « se ranger du bon côté » ([GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8894181/se-ranger-du-bon-cote)). Mais généralement j'aime bien « se joindre à » + « mouvement, cause, tendance/mode, folie », même si l'expression « join the cause » n'est pas exactement identique à « jump on the bandwagon ». Un contexte de phrase précis permettrait d'ajuster le registre, les compléments du verbe et de d'assurer que ce soit idiomatique.

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour Dimitris. Cette expression "jump on the bandwagon" peut se traduire de plusieurs manière sélon l'idée que l'on veut exprimer.
Par exemple - suivre le cours des choses - se focaliser sur la routine - se ranger du bon coté.
Sinon textuellement la traduction donne : sauter dans le wagon en marche.